# How to perform backward fill in SQL in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to derive a column in snowflake SQL query that is equivalent to fill function in tidyr package of R. I have added the Expected output column which basically has the TIMESTAMP2 value when accompanied with a future non-null value. I am able to get this done using LAST_VALUE as mentioned below but it is filling the last row of TIMESTAMP2 as well with 6/7/23 3:21 AM while I am expecting a NULL value over there as it is not accompanied by a future non-null value. Could someone please share their thoughts on this of what I am missing?

`LAST_VALUE(TIMESTAMP2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY A  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

[image]

````
Group TIMESTAMP1        TIMESTAMP2       Expected Output
A     11/22/21 7:24 AM  6/16/22 7:26 AM  6/16/22 7:26 AM
A     10/11/22 6:46 AM  NULL             5/11/23 3:17 AM
A     10/11/22 6:47 AM  NULL             5/11/23 3:17 AM
A     10/11/22 6:47 AM  NULL             5/11/23 3:17 AM
A     10/11/22 6:50 AM  NULL             5/11/23 3:17 AM
A     10/11/22 6:51 AM  5/11/23 3:17 AM  5/11/23 3:17 AM
A     5/30/23 5:22 AM   6/7/23 3:21 AM   6/7/23 3:21 AM
A     10/24/23 7:19 AM  NULL             NULL```
````

Comment: Could you please provide data as text not image ?

Comment: Added the data as text..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` should be in descending order :

```
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(TIMESTAMP2 IGNORE NULLS) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY Grp  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP1 DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS EXPECTED
FROM mytable
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP1;
```

Results :

```
GRP TIMESTAMP1      TIMESTAMP2      EXPECTED
A   2021-11-22 7:24 2022-06-16 7:26 2022-06-16 7:26
A   2022-10-11 6:46 null            23-05-11 3:17
A   2022-10-11 6:47 null            23-05-11 3:17
A   2022-10-11 6:47 null            23-05-11 3:17
A   2022-10-11 6:50 null            23-05-11 3:17
A   2022-10-11 6:51 23-05-11 3:17   23-05-11 3:17
A   2023-05-30 5:22 23-06-07 3:21   23-06-07 3:21
A   2023-10-24 7:19 null            null
```

[Demo on oracle 23](https://dbfiddle.uk/OuNDnYB_)